# Querying Communities?

Tags: apex, community

How (programatically) can I get a list of the Communities in an org to present to a System Administrator?

I've setup a community in my development org and published, and I can switch between the Internal org and the Support community using the dropdown int the top right. So far, so good.

However even though I can access and edit that community, I can't seem to find a way to get to it via code.

Running the query `select id, name from community` simply returns one community, the default Internal one.

Am I missing something obvious or is this just a non-starter?

Comment: ConnectApi.Communities.getCommunities() This yielded me the proper results with API version 29.

Comment: Gah! The version of MavensMate I'm using is calling using v28. Works fine in the dev console! Can you post that as the answer mate?

Comment: Posted that as an answer :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

ConnectApi.Communities.getCommunities()  This works from developer console as well as from apex class, but you must use **API 28.0** (or above).

> 11:56:52:193 USER_DEBUG [5]|DEBUG|ConnectApi.CommunityPage[buildVersion=28.0, communities=(ConnectApi.Community[buildVersion=28.0, description=funn2comunity, id=0DB90000000PBSLGA4, invitationsEnabled=false, name=Fun2community, sendWelcomeEmail=true, status=Live, url=/services/data/v28.0/connect/communities/0DB90000000PBSLGA4, urlPathPrefix=null], ConnectApi.Community[buildVersion=28.0, description=This is a funcommunity, id=0DB90000000PBQtGAO, invitationsEnabled=false, name=Funcommunity, sendWelcomeEmail=true, status=Live, url=/services/data/v28.0/connect/communities/0DB90000000PBQtGAO, urlPathPrefix=mainportal]), total=2]

Communities is called **Network** in the SObject API. So if you didn't want to use the ConnectApi, you could query Communities by running:

```
SELECT id, name FROM Network
```

Comment: @LaceySnr It worked with API 28.0.I think the bug is with mavens mate plugin .

Comment: Hmm, I'll investigate more. There's no reason for the code to behave differently when being run from different places, could be I was on an even older API version...

Comment: [1]|DEBUG|ConnectApi.CommunityPage[buildVersion=28.0, communities=(), total=0] your logs shows you were in version 28.0 .Anyways i will dig in as well

Comment: Hang about, I was being an idiot. When I ran the code from MM it was executing in a different org ;) Bet you need API 28+!

Comment: Was able to run it with 26th version as well.:)